# Host on .onion address on OSx

Tags: onion-services

How do you relay a local server to run on a .onion address on OSx? I have read the [Tor docs](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) and added the below line to my `torrc` file

```
HiddenServiceDir /Applications/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/hidden_service
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:4000
```

After saving and restarting Tor it will not open.

[image: tor not opening]

Comment: Can you post your tor log please?

Comment: I'm unable to find my tor log in `/var/log/tor` as stated in the docs (there's no tor folder)

Comment: Probably because `/var/log/tor` is the directory of the installed version of Tor, and not of the TBB. Can you re-run TBB, "Copy Tor Log To Clipboard" like your image says and past it in your question please?

Comment: The log says there are no errors: http://puu.sh/mN5Y0/96aee3dcec.png

Comment: Well, this is not so helpful. Can you try to setup your server but using tor like explained here (so installing it)? https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en .. because if you'll find the same error, probably the error isn't with tor.

Comment: How would I host a hidden service with Tor downloaded through Macports?

Comment: I've never used macports  but in the page linked there are some instruction, did you find some problems?

Comment: could it be that it does not have proper access to the ghidden service dir you specified? is there a hostfile generated there?

Answer (score -1):

If you're happy to install the Python library `txtorcon` (which gives you Twisted) then you should be able to do something like: `twistd -n web --port "onion:80" --path ~/public_html` which will launch a Tor if needed; `tor` should be in your PATH.

Similarly for sharing single files, there's `carml pastebin` (https://carml.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-pastebin.html) or OnionShare (https://onionshare.org/)

I don't think changing TBB's tor config is very suited to this, as exiting TBB will shut down Tor and therefore take your service offline.